# ReactiveMongo Connection, keep connection object alive in the Play context or re-establish for each call to the database? (Play, Scala, ReactiveMongo)

Tags: reactivemongo

I am just starting to use ReactiveMongo with Play 2 (scala).

Should I store a singleton object with the connection details and a return of the database (connection.get.db("mydb")) or keep the connection alive indefinitely.

I am used to JDBC connection pools so am unsure what the performant way to use ReactiveMongo and Mongo is.

Sorry if this is not very well formed question, I am fumbling in the dark a bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From this documentation

http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver

there is optional parameter

> *nbChannelsPerNode* Number of channels to open per node. Defaults to 10.

This looks like that the returned object (MongoConnection) is connection pool itself. So you should use it as singleton and not create a new instances for each request.